# Accuracy of finding electron's magnetic moment

Tags: experimental-physics, quantum-electrodynamics, error-analysis, magnetic-moment, quantum-measurements

In the little book QED, Feynman says:

> "experiments have Dirac’s number at 1.00115965221 (with an uncertainty of about 4 in the last digit); the theory puts it at 1.00115965246 (with an uncertainty of about five times as much)."

But this means experiment says Dirac's number is in the interval:
$$(1.00115965217, 1.00115965225)$$
(add and subtract 4 from last digit of experimental result)
and theory says it is in the interval:
$$(1.00115965226, 1.00115965266).$$
(add and subtract 4*5=20 from last digit of theoretical result)

but this two intervals have no intersection! and the theory crachs! where is great success?

Comment: Newer numbers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomalous_magnetic_dipole_moment#Electron

Comment: When a physical value has a stated uncertainty, it doesn’t mean that there is zero probability of the value lying outside what you call the “interval”.

Comment: So you are complaining about a difference in the 11th digit?

Comment: Then what does it mean? @Ghoster

Comment: It means that Feynman's book is, for one thing, outdated. There are newer publications (for specialists in the field) which are discussing the actually quite intricate details of these calculations. That quantum electrodynamics is sufficient to calculate the "ultimate" value for the anomalous magnetic moment is also not correct (and never was). A theory doesn't "crash" because it doesn't predict something with 100% accuracy. It simply demonstrates that there is something else that we are still missing. I don't believe the electron is the right system for that search. Muons might be.

Comment: Don Lincoln and FermiLab have made a number of videos. For example, [What does the Muon g-2 experiment tell us?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eCCGr4BqElE)

Comment: *Then what does it mean?* [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty): “When the uncertainty represents the standard error of the measurement, then about 68.3% of the time, the true value of the measured quantity falls within the stated uncertainty range.” Essentially, the uncertainty quantifies the “width” of a [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) (or “bell curve”) of possible values. There is a 31.7% chance that the actual value lies *outside* your interval (assuming the uncertainty number was for one standard deviation).

Comment: @Ghoster said very good answer. But I think others doesn't got question. There is long time such talks between mathematicians and physicists. If theory says something is definitely positive and experiment says it is definitely negative we have a great great conflict. There nothing special that threshold be zero. In my question the threshold is 1.001159652255.

Comment: If you think there is a threshold, you didn’t understand what I wrote. You are also using out-of-date values from a 38-year-old book. As Wikipedia says, “The QED prediction agrees with the experimentally measured value to more than 10 significant figures, making the magnetic moment of the electron the most accurately verified prediction in the history of physics.” The theory did not, as you wrote, “crach”. QED is a stunning success and one of the glories of human achievement.

Comment: I said "threshold" to say what was my question in the main post. and the question was of course before reading your answer. I accepted your commet "When a physical value has a..." and it says there is no threshold in physical experiment like intervals in math. @Ghoster

Comment: I do not understand why this post has 5 down votes?

Comment: @Farcher it is a mystery also to me, there is plenty of trivial/homework/low-quality questions on PSE with zero or positive score. At least this one shows some original thinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forgetting that you used outdated values you have highlighted "good news" as far as the current crop of Physicists are concerned!

The difference between the experimental value and the theoretical value has to be judged on the balance of probability, that is why uncertainties in the values are included.
Using the uncertainties on can judge how likely it is that the two values are really different.

So why is a difference "good news"?
The theoretical value has been calculated using the standard model of particle physics and given that it agrees with the experimental value to so many significant figures one can say that the standard model is very, very good but . . . . . . not perfect.  It is that lack of perfection which gives Physicists scope to explore new theories which might amend the current standard model to get better agreement between the two values - that is the "good news".
The discrepancy between theory and experiment for a muon is much larger than for an electron and is subject to much research so that we can further the development of the standard model (or indeed introduce another model).

As a final point one must realise that the theoretical value of the magnetic moment depends of the experimental values of other constants and in particular the fine structure constant.
At present at least two groups are trying to get their experimental values for that constant to agree with one another to a sufficient degree of accuracy which in turn will increase the accuracy of the theoretical values for the magnetic moments.

Answer (score 1):

If theory and experiment disagree then, depending on the confidence level of the disagreement, it's most likely that something is wrong with the experiment or theory. There's a small chance it could be that we were just unlucky and got enough statistical outliers to throw the two out of agreement. If that was the case then running the same experiments (including the ones that inform the theory) more times should move towards eventual agreement.