# Certainty interval in physical measurements

Tags: experimental-physics, measurements, error-analysis

Let we have the result of a physical measurement like this:

> "Experiments have Dirac’s number at 1.00115965221 with
> an uncertainty of about 4 in the last digit"

Is this gives any interval that we could say certainly Dirac's number is within it? I mean exact certainty like $3<\pi<4$. If so what is smallest such an interval?

I wish there was such an interval like this: by common method of measurment by a long ruler my height is 1.863 meters and I'm uncertain about the last digit, but by this measurment I'm sure my height is in interval $[1.2m , 2.5m]$.

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/767753/2451

Comment: You can have very high confidence that the measured value is within several standard deviations. For example, the [chance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Standard_deviation_and_coverage) that it is outside a $\pm6 \sigma$ interval is only about 1 in 500 million. The bell curve quickly become negligible. Your problem seems to be that you would like exact certainty rather than very high confidence. You should simply adjust your expectations to suit science rather than mathematics.

Comment: I would appreciate it if you would please see my comment under the answer below by Dale and give your opinion @Ghoster

Comment: Please see this: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/129317/79678. The referenced document is freely available on the internet and is authored by professional metrologists, i.e., people who are specialist experts in measurement issues.

Comment: Duplicate from same OP with good answers: [Accuracy of finding electron's magnetic moment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/767753/accuracy-of-finding-electrons-magnetic-moment)

Answer (score 2):

No. Usually the uncertainty cited is the combined standard uncertainty. For a normally distributed uncertainty that would correspond to an interval with a 68 % probability of containing the measurand. That means there is a 32 % probability that the measurand is not in that interval.

You can increase the odds by reporting the expanded uncertainty instead. That might give an interval containing the measurand with 95 % probability. But there is still 5 % probability that the measurand is outside that interval.

The only way to make a “certainty interval” is to take all possible values, e.g. $(-\infty,\infty)$ for a measurand that can be negative or $[0,\infty)$ for a non-negative measurand.

Comment: It’s certain that the length of this ruler is a positive real number

Comment: Yes. Hence my last comment in the answer

Comment: I think may be physicists simply forget when normal distribution come to this game. just like somebody simply FORGETS my height is CERTAINLY positive. then looks at out come of my height measurment which is some thing like normal distribution about 1.86m and when I ask is my height is CERTAINLY posivitve he say of course NO. I think when I measure my height after some measurment and BEFORE need for normal distribution, I find my height is CERTAINLY in interval [1.70m, 2.00m]. THEN I look to approximately normally distributed... @Dale

Comment: ... measured numbers about 1.86m and ask is it CERTAIN that my height is taller than 1.80m and answer in NO. but I shouldn't stretch the tails of normall bell to out of pre-normal-approximation interval [1.70, 2.00] just as I shouldn't stretch the tails of normall bell to out of pre-normal-approximation interval [0, \infty]. @Dale

Comment: @moshtaba sorry, but if you want certainty you have to go ridiculously far. We are not certain that your height is in the interval [1.70 m, 2.00 m]. Also, it turns out that the normal distribution is usually overly optimistic. It isn’t that a normal approximation “stretches the tails” out too much. In fact, the problem is the opposite. Usually the normal distribution has tails that are too thin to accurately model the actual uncertainty in the tails

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is not enough information given for you to be able to give any certain interval, even if there is one, bar the trivial constraint that we know that the Dirac number (I assume you mean the one defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_large_numbers_hypothesis)) is the ratio of two positive numbers and so must be $>0$.

However, this latter point illustrates why taking the "normal distribution" interpretation of the quoted error bar too far beyond perhaps a few error bars would often be incorrect. The normal distribution with a standard deviation equal to the error bar would give a finite probability of having a negative result.

In practice, to say anything definitely quantitative about the low-probability tails of the posterior probability distribution is usually difficult and there is certainly no information contained about it within a single significant figure quoted as an error bar or the sentence you have quoted.

Answer (score 1):

The statement "the uncertainty is $4\cdot 10^{-11}$" can only be made using a distribution function of the random error. Two commonly used distribution functions are (1) normal distribution, and (2) uniform distribution within an interval $[a,b]$. If we use the normal distribution function, we are unable to give a finite confidence interval, which possesses 100% of the probability. In contrast, if the uncertainty statement was made using the uniform distribution function, such a finite interval exists. Therefore, your answer lies in the details of the statement, which are often omitted.